# POST value only when Checkbox is checked

Tags: php, html

I´ve got an table with an id from a mysql database. In every row from the table there is a checkbox and an input `type="number"`. I can send the id´s via POST if checkbox is checked. 
Now to my problem: The number of the input are ALWAYS send. But i want to get the right number of the right row.

```css
table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead td {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>checkbox</td>
      <td>number</td>
    </tr>
    
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<h1>Output in other PHP file should be:</h1>
<h3>Just say, we are checking 1 and 3. Number 1 = 4; Number 2=1; Number 3=2</h3><br>

<p>array"number": [0] => 4; [3] => 2</p>
<p>array"checkbox": [0] => 1; [2] => 3</p>

<h1>But my print_r shows (what is clear ...)</h1>
<p>array"number": [0] => 4, [1] => 1 ,[2] => 2  --- See my problem?</p>
<p>array"checkbox": [0] => 1, [3] => 3</p>
```

For unclear question etc. i´m sorry. Hope you understood me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the text boxes initially and when the checkbox is checked you can make the text box enable and put your value. Disabled input fields don't post. You can have a look on the below code, it may help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
   $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
     else
      $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');  
  
    });
});
```

```css
table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead td {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" >
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<td>id</td>
      <td>checkbox</td>
      <td>number</td>
    </tr>
    
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3">
      <td><input type="number" name="number[]" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" disabled ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```